# thymeleaf environment property in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

Is there any way to obtain the `auth0.domain` from `application.yml` in a shorter way? I know that for HTML you can use `th:utext="#{auth0.domain}"'` but how about JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const auth0Domain = '[[${@environment.getProperty("auth0.domain")}]]';
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the question... you really just want a shorter way?  Does `const auth0Domain = /*[[#{auth0.domain}]]*/ "";` not work?

Comment: Afaik, there is no shorter way, except you can omit the single quotes when using the double square brackets. Using `#{}` is for messages from a messages.properties file, I don't expect that this will work. You could add a model value in your controller, this way you could use `const auth0Domain = [[$("yourvariablename")]]`, but then it's more code hidden in the controller.